# The skeleton is naked of / from meat?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Which preposition is idiomatic to use in this context?

> This skeleton is naked **of / from** its meat.

I mean to say that this animal / human skeleton which is from 500 years ago,  is without meat / tissues.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to say. Can you give more details?

Comment: I added more details.

Comment: I don't think you can use "naked" to describe that. From Collins, *if an animal or part of an animal is naked, it has no fur or feathers on it.* Are you open to changing that verb?

Comment: I see. Yes, I am.

Comment: I suggest you use _flesh_ ; _meat_ is only used in the context of food.

Answer (score 2):

I think "naked" in this case can be used figuratively; or perhaps for stylistic reasons.

> *"A skeleton is a human being in its most naked form."* - [Your Bones Live On Without You](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2017/10/your-bones-live-on-without-you/543312/)

This doesn't appear to be the case with your sentence. A naked skeleton would be one with flesh on it, but not fur or skin.

From Collins, *if an animal or part of an animal is naked, it has no fur or feathers on it.*

You *could* say

> This skeleton has no flesh.

but that would sound weird because "no flesh" is built into (or implied by) the definition of "skeleton". This is what James K said in his answer.

You could rephrase your sentence to use the term *"skeletal remains"*.

> *"Skeletal remains are all that is left of a corpse after nature has taken its course and has disposed of skin, tissue, and any other organ that may cover the skeletal frame."* - [Explore Forensics](http://www.exploreforensics.co.uk/skeletal-remains.html)

You can say something like this:

> Skeletal remains from [a person who died] 500 years ago were found buried under ...

or

> Skeletal remains of [...] were discovered in ...

You can of course say it in many other ways:

> The remains consisted of a skull, a hip bone, two femurs, [...]; there was no flesh or tissue.
>
> The flesh has completely decayed/decomposed; the bones are what's left of ...
>
> We found the remains of a [...] from 500 years ago; there is no flesh anymore, just bones.

Answer (score 1):

A skeleton can be "stripped of its flesh".  This would perhaps be most often used of a skeleton that is quite young:

> After death, the body is placed on a podium until the skeleton is stripped of its flesh by birds. The bones are then placed in a pot, which is buried outside the village.

Otherwise, a "skeleton" implies that there is no flesh remaining.

> We opened the coffin to see only a skeleton wearing a crown and still holding a rusting iron sword.

You can say "There was no flesh on the bones." if you want to be explicit.